# NGINX acceder a multiples sitios desde la misma IP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7, nginx

Quisiera saber como puedo tener varios sitios en Nginx y poder acceder a cada uno de ellos con la misma IP (sin el dominio, ya que estoy haciendo pruebas en un laboratorio localmente).

El servidor lo tengo en una PC aparte y accedo remotamente desde mi computadora mediante la IP. Ambos estan en la misma red LAN

En el directorio /var/www/ tengo dos sitios 'nextcloud' y 'phpmyadmin'. Quisiera poder ingresar a ambos colocando (por ejemplo) 192.168.1.14/nextcloud y 192.168.1.14/phpmyadmin. O teniendo cualquier otro proyecto en el directorio www.

Intente todas las soluciones que encontre, pero ninguna de ellas me ha funcionado. Cuando ingreso a phpmyadmin por ejemplo, me da para descargar la pagina en lugar de entrar a ella.

Dentro de /etc/nginx/sites-enabled tengo los dos archivos, uno de nextcloud:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/nextcloud/;

        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name  localhost;

        client_max_body_size 512M;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        location / {
            root /var/www/nextcloud;
        rewrite ^ /index.php$request_uri;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+)\.php(?:$|/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
            try_files $uri/ =404;
            index index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff|svg|gif)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
            access_log off;
        }
    }
```

Y la de phpmyadmin:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/phpmyadmin/;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }
```

Probe creando dos carpetas de prueba en /var/www/ (test1 y test2), cada una de ellas con un archivo index.html dentro y modificando el archivo default de nginx, pero tampoco me ha funcionado

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name localhost;

        index index.html;

        location / {
            return 410;  # Default root of site won't exist.
        }

        location /test1/ {
            alias /var/www/test1/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            # any additional configuration for non-static content
        }

        location /test2/ {
            alias /var/www/test2/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            # any additional configuration for non-static content
        }
    }
```

Como habia dicho, probe distintas soluciones. Otro problema que tuve fue que solo me redireccionaba a nextcloud, aunque coloque phpmyadmin en la url. Y el anterior que ya mencione, que cuando ingreso, descarga el index.php. Muchas gracias